# gcc doesn't include c header file json-c

Tags: c, json, gcc, header-files, json-c

On  Macbook, I am making something with json-c(https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

```
gcc a.c
a.c:1:10: fatal error: 'json.h' file not found
#include "json.h"
          ^
1 error generated.`>
```

when I try to compile it,

it prints out error, but I have `json.h` file in include file.

```
> cd /usr/local/include/json-c/
> ls
arraylist.h            json_config.h          json_tokener.h
bits.h                 json_inttypes.h        json_util.h
debug.h                json_object.h          linkhash.h
json.h                 json_object_iterator.h printbuf.h
json_c_version.h       json_object_private.h  random_seed.h
```

/usr/include/json-c/json.h is definitely exists

Comment: Give the path to your header files

`gcc -I/usr/local/include/json-c/ a.c`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely that the compiler doesn't have the `json-c` subdirectory in its include path.

With luck, you can just add that to your inclusion:

```
#include "json-c/json.h"
```

This only works if that header is stand-alone, i.e. it doesn't reference any further headers in `json-c/`.

If that fails you have to tell the compiler when you invoke it:

```
$ gcc -I/usr/local/include/json-c/ a.c
```